# Include Form Title in Freeform Notification

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to make a single Notification template for a general auto-response to several forms and would like to include the form's title in the subject line and body. To be sure, this is not {form_name}. I hoped {nonfield_title} would do the trick, but it does not output the title as it does on the live page. Any tips?

Comment: This question isn't 100% clear upon reading it. I'd suggest fine-tuning and adding more information to ensure you get good answers. Screenshots would be great so we know exactly what you're doing and where.

Comment: I was simply looking for the general tag to include a form's title within Notifications. Timo Häkkinen got it below with {form_label}. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, it's {form_label}.

When you create a form, it says "Form Label: This is the full name of the Form." When you add "Title" in composer, this gets outputted as nonfield_title.

You can use {form_label} in notification's Subject as well as Email message. You could even make "{form_label} - {name}" the subject, assuming you have a name field.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question whether you are putting this information into the form or the notification template.

Create a hidden input field in your form containing the information you want. You can then include this custom field in your notification template.

You could pass that information to the form via an embed parameter, hardcode it or use the [{form_info}](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form_info/) tag pair to output information that can be included in your notification.